# Sentinel-2 dataset on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I'm new at Google Earth Engine and Javascript.
According to this https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/COPERNICUS%2FS2, it is possible to load/add a Sentinel-2 granule by naming the image like this:

COPERNICUS/S2/20151128T002653_20151128T102149_T56MNN

So, in my case, I've tried to load an existing Sentinel-2 granule, writing this:

```
var senti_img1 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20150803T170236_20160825T061733_T15SXD");
Map.setCenter(+81.635027777777778,7.29283333333333,15);
```

It worked. But when I changed the dates to get another data set that's not working. 
for example when i tried with followings I got an error -

new2B2: Layer error: Image.load: Image asset 'COPERNICUS/S2/20150803T170236_20180725T061733_T15SXD' not found.

```
var senti_img1 = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20180603T170236_20190625T061733_T15SXD");


var img1B1 = senti_img1.select('B1');
var img1B3 = senti_img1.select('B3');

var chl1 = ((senti_img1.select('B3') / (senti_img1.select('B1')))^(3.94))*(4.23);
print(chl1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you are looking for  is not currently available in the Google Earth Engine repository. If you know that the image exists, you should report it.

The best way to know if an image is in the repository is creating a collection and then printing it.

For example, if you want to check the images of the tile T15SXD in june 2018 write the following:

```
// create collection using tile and date
var sentinel2_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2").
filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '29TNH').
filterDate('2018-06-01', '2018-06-30');

// write collection to the console
print(sentinel2_collection)
```